# Fullcalendar, icalendar extension use

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, icalendar

I use the Fullcalendar library to display a calendar on my site where my calendar data is in .ics format.
I can display the calendar, but displaying the data in it's another story. So, I need help finding out how to display the data in an ics file in the Fullcalendar calendar. Thank you for your attention!

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/icalendar

Comment: Please add some code, what did you try? Please read [ask] and [mre]